# Spacemacs: kill buffer and kill window in one command?

Tags: buffers, spacemacs, files

Is there a spacemacs command that both closes the window and kills the buffer? In other words, the equivalent of Vim's `:q`?

Comment: There is `SPC q Q` for (kill-emacs) - which I guess is the equivalent of :q? If you want an explicit kill buffer kill window command, why don't you write it and add to your `spacemacs-user-config`?

Comment: @dangom In Vim `:q` closes the current window only, it only exits Vim if you are down to your last window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spacemacs has [recently added](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/10139) two shortcuts for `kill-buffer-and-window`: `SPC b x` and `SPC w x`.

Comment: For others that like me are wondering about this, this is not only in Spacemacs. It is added to Emacs itself with vanilla Emacs default binding of `C-x 4 0`. It can be found in `window.el`.

Answer (score 18):

spacemacs binding for `kill-buffer-and-window`:

<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

Use `kill-buffer-and-window` to close a buffer and its window. But this will keep emacs running. If you also want to kill emacs (the equivalent of `:q`) then try `evil-quit-all` if you're using evil, and `save-buffers-kill-terminal` for standard emacs quit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answers, in particular the one by sid-kap; for people not on the development branch, i.e. people using the current stable release, the command `kill-buffer-and-window` is bound to `SPC u SPC w d` as described (currently) in [the key bindings section](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/DOCUMENTATION.org#window-manipulation-key-bindings) of the documentation.