# Is there a way to write and kill a buffer in a single command in Spacemacs / Evil?

Tags: spacemacs, evil

I am new to (Spac)Emacs with Evil, and I did quite some searching to find an answer to this question, so I hope this is a 'legitimate' question here.

Is there a default single command to write a buffer and kill only the buffer instead of quitting Emacs. I found answers for how to just quit a buffer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28914/spacemacs-kill-buffer-and-kill-window-in-one-command/28944#28944) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacemacs/comments/6p3w0l) but I do not know how to do the same thing including saving the buffer in one command. For example, I can delete the buffer with `:bd`, but `:wbd` does not work.

If there is no default way, then what is a nice alternative to get this job done (in a single command of course).

Comment: Only after I asked this question I looked up how to actually get this done in emacs (not spacemacs). So I found a reasonable alternative to :wq (without killing emacs) using the key combination `C-x C-s C-x k`. But still a more spacemacs-like alternative would be nice too...

Comment: Just a nitpick: your question (and comment/answer) is really about Evil rather than about Spacemacs.  I've seen many people confuse the two.

Comment: @Stefan I agree, thanks for pointing that out. I slightly edited the question to include its relation with evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no such command in Vim, there won't be one in Evil either. If there is one, but it doesn't work right, consider reporting a bug. `:wbd` isn't a thing in my Vim, but it's not hard to recreate it with a bit of Emacs Lisp:

```
(evil-define-command evil-write-and-kill-buffer (path)
  "Save and kill buffer."
  :repeat nil
  :move-point nil
  (interactive "<f>")
  (if (zerop (length path))
      (save-buffer)
    (write-file path))
  (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))

(evil-ex-define-cmd "wbd[elete]" 'evil-write-and-kill-buffer)
```

Comment: I did not realize that I never used this in vim. I only worked half a year in vim and used to open multiple files in multiple windows (switching windows with alt+` in gnome is quite efficient too for simple projects). I checked now how this would work in (neo)vim and I found that the command `:w|bd` does the job. I tested this command in evil too but it writes a file named |bd so I will consider to file a bug then. Anyway, thanks for your great answer! I will accept it after I tested it but for now as I said I am new to (Spac)Emacs and Evil. @wasamasa